# Baking texture in Three.js

Tags: three.js, textures

I have a textured model and I load my model in Three.js.

For some reasons, I need to bake light effects on the current texture of the my model. Basically, I want to do 'texture baking'. I want to render all effects on the texture.

Any ideas to achieve this in Three.js (webgl)?

Comment: Can you clarify this phrase "_to bake light effects on ... texture_"? Have you tried something already? Code samples (codepen, jsfiddle).

Comment: I want to do 'Texture baking'. Not to recalculate light and shadow effects, I want to render onto the textures.

Comment: Texture baking is generally something you do offline.

Comment: agree with gman, however, if you really do need to do this, you can transform your object into 2d space instead of 3d, `gl_Position = vec4( myUv , 0. ,1.);`. Calculate the light as if each fragment was in world space et voila youve got yourself some "baked light effects".